# Split a string by three delimiters, and adding them to different lists

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm making a quiz game in Python. So far, the program reads in a file. In the file is something like this:

```
Poles|Magnet|?|Battery
```

The game works by the user guessing what fills the "?" part.

I can already split the string into 4 separate parts by splitting at the `|` character, but now I want to add this to the end:

```
Poles|Magnet|?|Battery/!Charge/Ends/Magic/Metal
```

I have no idea how to make the program do this:

1. Split the first four into a list.

I've done this bit:

```
# Read questions in from a file.
with open("questions.txt", "r") as questions:
    data = questions.read().split("|")
    for x in range(0,4):
        print(data[x])
```

2. Split the second four into another list.
3. THEN look which one has a `!` at the start (signifying that it is the correct answer) and put this into a string, like `answer`. Then the user's input can be tested against that.

Here is the full thing so far:

```
# Quick Thinker!

import os

def buildQuestions():
# Read questions in from a file.
with open("questions.txt", "r") as questions:
    data = questions.read().split("|")
    for x in range(0,4):
        print(data[x])


def intro():
print("        ____        _      _      _______ _     _       _             _ ")
print("       / __ \      (_)    | |    |__   __| |   (_)     | |           | |")
print("      | |  | |_   _ _  ___| | __    | |  | |__  _ _ __ | | _____ _ __| |")
print("      | |  | | | | | |/ __| |/ /    | |  | '_ \| | '_ \| |/ / _ \ '__| |")
print("      | |__| | |_| | | (__|   <     | |  | | | | | | | |   <  __/ |  |_|")
print("        \___\_\\__,_|_|\___|_|\_\    |_|  |_| |_|_|_| |_|_|\_\___|_|  (_)")
print("                                                                  ")
input("")
os.system("cls")
print("Welcome to the game!")
print("In QUICKTHINKER, you must select the correct missing entry from a sequence.")
print("")
print("For Example: ")
print("")
print("PEACE | CHAOS | CREATION | ?")
print("")
print("A: MANUFACTURE")
print("B: BUILD")
print("C: DESTRUCTION")
print("")
print("The correct answer for this would be DESTRUCTION.")
print("")
print("There will be, more or less, no pattern between questions.")
print("Each have their own logic.")
input("")
os.system("cls")

intro()
buildQuestions()
input("")
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

## Edit

Don't know whether to make this into another question or not, but how would I strip the `!` from the `answers` list, so that when it is displayed there isn't any `!` there to signify the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. First it splits by the `|`. The last element of that contains your answers. Then we remove the answers from the keys. Now we split the answers into their parts. Finally we get the correct answer by searching for the `!` and save that in the string `answer`.

```
with open("questions.txt", "r") as questions:
    keys = questions.read().split('|')
    answers = keys[3]
    keys[3] = keys[3].split('/', 1)[0]

    answers = answers.split('/')[1:]

    answer = [x for x in answers if '!' in x][0].strip('!')

    answers = [x.strip('!') for x in answers]

    print(keys)
    print(answers)
    print(answer)
```

Output

```
['Poles', 'Magnet', '?', 'Battery']
['Charge', 'Ends', 'Magic', 'Metal']
Charge
```

Comment: Don't know whether to make this into another question or not, but how would I strip the `!` from the `answers` list, so that when it is displayed there isn't any `!` there to signify the answer?

Comment: I updated my answer. To strip the `!` from the answers, you can user the strip function on each element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split`:

```
s = "Poles|Magnet|?|Battery/!Charge/Ends/Magic/Metal"

spl = re.split("[|/]",s)
a,b = spl[:4],spl[4:]
print(a,b)
(['Poles', 'Magnet', '?', 'Battery'], ['!Charge', 'Ends', 'Magic', 'Metal'])
```

If you just want the string that has the `!`:

```
answer = next(x for x in spl if x.startswith("!"))
print(answer)
!Charge
```

If you need to know which list it was in:

```
answer_a,answer_b = next((x for x in a if x.startswith("!")),""), next((x for x in b if x.startswith("!")),"")
print("The answer {} was in list1".format(answer_a) if answer_a else "The answer {} was in list2".format(answer_b))

The answer !Charge was in list2
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my poin-of-view, if we can add one more delimiter, everything will be so easy to work with :D
**NOTE**: You may have sometime more than 4 options

```
Poles|Magnet|?|Battery-!Charge/Ends/Magic/Metal
```

or

```
Poles|Magnet|?|Battery-Ends/!Charge/Magic/Metal
```

In such a scenario, we don`t need so complicated answers ;) I don`t think if you implement your game like this, you need anymore help for this problem. It is so simple now -

First, split with "-" , you get 2 lists. Then, split list1 with "|" and list2 with "/". :D

Moreover, please add the comment, if you still want the solution of previous problem, i can try for that also.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably take a similar approach to the accepted answer, but I'd handle it a little differently. The thing you have to realize here is that what you have is a comma-separated values file. Suuuure, you're not using commas, but this is still a `csv` file. Since you have a `csv` file, let's use the `csv` module to handle it!

```
import csv

questions = []
# we'll build dicts with questions of the format:
# {'prompts': ['Poles', 'Magnet', 'Battery'],
#  'answers: ['Ends','Charge','Magic','Metal'],
#  'correct: 'Charge'}

with open("path/to/file.txt") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|")
    for row in reader:
        d = {}
        prompts = row[:-1] # everything but the last entry is a prompt
        answers = []
        for ans in row[-1].split("/"):
            if ans.startswith("!")
                correct = ans.strip("!")
            answers.append(ans.strip("!"))
        d['prompts'] = prompts
        d['answers'] = answers
        d['correct'] = correct
        questions.append(d)
```

Once this is all done and out of the way, you'll end up with a list like this:

```
questions = [ {'prompts': ['Poles', 'Magnet', 'Battery'],
               'answers: ['Ends','Charge','Magic','Metal'],
               'correct: 'Charge'},
              {'prompts': ['Peace','Chaos','Creation'],
               'answers: ['Manufacture','Build','Destruction'],
               'correct: 'Destruction'}, ... ]
```

This is useful because your whole quiz then is:

```
for question in questions:
    print(" | ".join(question['prompts']) + " | ?")
    print()
    mapping = dict(zip(question['answers'], "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
    # this will make sure we can test the answer afterwards
    for answer in question['answers']:
        print(mapping[answer] + ". " + answer)
    response = input(">> ")
    correct_response = mapping[question['correct']]
    if response == correct_response:
        # handle correct answers here. Maybe score += 1?
    else:
        # handle incorrect answers here
```