# Remove a certain character from a list, after adding one element of it to a string already

Tags: python, string

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041324/split-a-string-by-three-delimiters-and-adding-them-to-different-lists) yesterday, and now I've hit another problem.

The code so far:

```
with open("questions.txt", "r") as questions:
    keys = questions.read().split('|')
    answers = keys[3]
    keys[3] = keys[3].split('/', 1)[0]

    answers = answers.split('/')[1:]
    answer = [x for x in answers if '!' in x][0][1:]

    #print(keys)
    #print(answers)
    #print(answer)

    for x in range(0,4):
        print(keys[x])
    print("")
    for y in range(0,4):
        print(answers[y])

    userAnswer = input("Enter your answer!: ").lower()

    if userAnswer == answer:
        print("Correct!")
        input("")
```

This worked fine, but now when I displayed the `answers` list, the first entry on the list had a `!` before it, which was only there to let the program figure out which one was the right answer. Now I want to, after letting the program add the correct answer to the string `answer`, strip the list of the character `!`.

```
answers = answers.split('/')[1:]
answer = [x for x in answers if '!' in x][0][1:]

#Code would likely fit here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already found the correct answer and no longer need the version with the `!` in front of it, you can do the following:

```
answers = answers.split('/')[1:]
answer = [x for x in answers if '!' in x][0][1:]

#Code would likely fit here
answers[answers.index('!' + answer)] = answer
```

This finds the index of the correct answer in the list with the exclamation point in front of it, and replaces it with a version that does not contain the exclamation point. Now when you use the `answers` list in the future, it will be formatted correctly. Since we know that only one answer will have an exclamation point in front of it, we can just change this one occurrence rather than iterating over the entire list.

Alternatively, if you want to maintain a version of the list with the exclamation point still in the list, you can simply strip the `!` when printing out the answer choices. To do this, you can change

```
for y in range(0,4):    
    print(answers[y])
```

to

```
for ans in answers:
    ans[1:] if a.startswith('!') else ans
```

In our print statement, we simply check if the first character of the string to print is `!`, and if it is, then strip off the first character. Otherwise we print it as normal.

Something to note about this change - there is no need to iterate over a range in python as you did. Rather than looping through a range of numbers and looking at the element at each index in that list, you can simply loop through every element. This allows us to go from:

```
for y in range(0,4):
    print answers[y]
```

to simply:

```
for y in answers:
    print y
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options. You could eliminate it in the print.

```
for y in range(0,4):
    if answers[y].startswith('!'):
        print(answers[y][1:])
    else:
        print(answers[y])
```

more pythonically rewritten as

```
for a in answers:
    if a.startswith('!'):
        print(a[1:])
    else:
        print(a)
```

or actually remove it from the list.

```
answers = [a[1:] if a.startswith('!') else a for a in answers]
```

Also beware your last option still contains the newline from the file. Eliminate this using.

```
keys = questions.read().strip().split('|')
```